# Svelte vs MarkoJS

Tags: svelte, marko

I’m working on rebuilding a new project for many reasons. Currently the project uses Marko.
I’m investigating if it’s worth moving to svelte.
I actually didn’t find a big difference between them.
Does one of them has advantage on the other? Why the big hype around Svelte?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question.  Unfortunately, since this question is *primarily opinion-based*, it is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and will likely be closed.  You might try asking if anyone has a comparison between Svelte and Marko in the [Svelte Discord chatroom](https://svelte.dev/chat); I believe it would be on-topic there.

Comment: I'd consider sticking which Marko because of where it is headed... and I like Svelte! [FLUURT: Re-inventing Marko](https://dev.to/ryansolid/fluurt-re-inventing-marko-3o1o) [Maybe you don’t need that SPA](https://medium.com/@mlrawlings/maybe-you-dont-need-that-spa-f2c659bc7fec)

Comment: Could you elaborate about that and provide the reasons why you're rebuilding a fresh project?

Answer (score 19):

In my view Svelte's popularity is based on the fact that:

1. it tends to lead to smaller JS client bundle sizes than the big three (React, Vue, Angular) and can still outperform them on a broad range of applications, *especially* on low spec/power client devices.
2. it's fairly easy to learn once you have a good grasp of JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

I would go as far as saying that Svelte feels more like a natural extension to the browser platform while the big three tend to do "their own thing" (Angular being an "opinionated" framework, React obsessing over `fn(state) => view` and Vue sitting in between).
The code savings (and "client battery friendliness") in Svelte are largely due to it [not using a VDOM](https://svelte.dev/blog/virtual-dom-is-pure-overhead) like React and Vue - that translates to less code downloaded and fewer CPU cycles burned. Also Svelte uses a compiler to generate code so it only includes what is actually needed - even before the bundler's tree-shaking gets to do its thing. Svelte uses a reactive update model instead (there are actually two systems: [reactive assignments](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-assignments) and [stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores))

The downside to Svelte is that at this point in time its ecosystem is much smaller compared to any of the big three - but that is to be expected as it is a much younger tool.

Rich Harris has given some excellent talks about Svelte:

- [Rethinking reactivity](https://youtu.be/AdNJ3fydeao)
- [The Return of 'Write Less, Do More'](https://youtu.be/BzX4aTRPzno)

See also [MDN: Getting started with Svelte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_getting_started)

However just like React and Vue, Svelte's core design is based on [CSR](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web#csr) - Client Side Rendering. So while all of them have SSR solutions ([Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) - React, [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) - Vue, [SvelteKit](https://svelte.dev/blog/whats-the-deal-with-sveltekit) - formerly Sapper) these solutions tend to introduce some accidental complexity because SSR wasn't part of the initial design.

This is where Marko is different. It started as a server-based solution with a client-based aspect. Back in 2017 that client-based aspect [was VDOM based](https://medium.com/hackernoon/marko-vs-react-an-in-depth-look-767de0a5f9a6). One of the advantages of Marko is that it supports [Async Fragments](https://tech.ebayinc.com/engineering/async-fragments-rediscovering-progressive-html-rendering-with-marko/) - streaming of HTML from the server - out of the box. Now Marko plans to ditch the VDOM and replace it with [fine grained reactivity](https://indepth.dev/posts/1269/finding-fine-grained-reactive-programming) to reduce the size of shipped code and improve performance on low-end client devices. Ryan Carniato of [Solid JS](https://github.com/ryansolid/solid) joined the [Marko Team in July 2020](https://dev.to/ryansolid/i-m-joining-the-markojs-core-team-2fc1) to make that happen.

In that sense Marko is unique as it implements an approach that tries leverage the strengths of both parties involved in any web application - the server and the client - in an integrated manner. As such it seems ideally suited for the [Islands Architecture](https://jasonformat.com/islands-architecture/) something that needs a bit more work in Svelte ([Elder.js](https://elderguide.com/tech/elderjs/) and its [backstory](https://nicholasreese.com/lessons-from-building-a-static-site-generator/)).

- [Maybe you don’t need that SPA](https://medium.com/@mlrawlings/maybe-you-dont-need-that-spa-f2c659bc7fec)
- [A First Look at MarkoJS](https://dev.to/ryansolid/a-first-look-at-markojs-3h78)
- [FLUURT: Re-inventing Marko](https://dev.to/ryansolid/fluurt-re-inventing-marko-3o1o)
- [Marko: Designing a UI Language](https://dev.to/ryansolid/marko-designing-a-ui-language-2hni)

In terms of taglines: [Marko is HTML re-imagined](https://markojs.com/docs/syntax/#syntax) while Svelte is [using a superset of HTML](https://svelte.dev/docs#Component_format).